# ARM debugging interesting behavior

Tags: debugging, arm

I was just disassembling and debugging an ARM binary for fun and I noticed something unusual. Consider the following set of instructions:-

```
   0x00008058 <+4>: mov r1, pc
   0x0000805c <+8>: add r1, r1, #24
   0x00008060 <+12>:    mov r0, #1
```

I tried setting a breakpoint at `0x0000805c` and checked the value of the register `r1`. I was expecting to see `0x0000805c` -- however, interestingly the value is `0x8060`.

Why is this? Is this because of some sort of instruction pipelineing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's because of pipelining.

From http://winarm.scienceprog.com/arm-mcu-types/how-does-arm7-pipelining-works.html --

> [image: ARM pipelining]
>
> PC (Program Counter) is calculated **8 bytes ahead** of current
>   instruction.